# What is unsafe HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, security

I was reading about $sce in AngularJS and it says in its documents that $sce is used -

> to sanitize unsafe HTML before binding to the value and rendering it
>   in the document

I wondered how an HTML snippet can harm any web application.

Can anyone explain it with the help of a scenario about how `'unsafe HTML'` work and harm web applications?

Comment: reason for downvote !!!

Comment: improper html may open up to attacking.  please research on Cross site scripting, query injection etc

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why all the down votes. Anyways, the biggest thing I am aware of is best practices to avoid XSS (cross site scripting). The three main rules are:

> 1. HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content
> 2. Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes
> 3. JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into JavaScript Data Values
> 4. (Actually 3.1) HTML escape JSON values in an HTML context and read the data with JSON.parse

I feel like I can explain them all separately but here's the article explaining everything in details: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet